Nested formula with different conditons
In my Excel spreadsheet:
Cell P2 = January, February, March, April.. December
Cell Q2 = 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029.. 2036

Cell R2 has the following formula:
=IF(Q2=2024,"Leap Year",IF(Q2=2028,"Leap Year",IF(Q2=2032,"Leap Year",IF(Q2=2036,"Leap Year",""))))

Cell P3 has the following formula which returns the total number of days based on what month is in cell P2:
=IF(P2="April","30",IF(P2="June","30",IF(P2="September","30",IF(P2="November","30","31"))))

Now what I need is to add this formula in the same cell P3:
=IF(AND(P2="February",R2="Leap Year"),29,28)

So, when I select the month of February and the value in Cell R2 is showing Leap Year, I want the total days to show 29 and if no Leap Year is showing, the total days should revert to 28.
Can you please assist?

I have used list for the months and years, then changed your formulae. There is a simpler formula to test for leap years found here. I have adapted it to dynamically build the dates, months and years instead of hard coding them into the formulae.

For leap years or not:

=IF(MONTH(DATE(YEAR("01 " & P2 & " " & Q2),2,29))=2,"Leap year", "Not leap year")



For the number of days in a month:

=DAY(EOMONTH("01 " & P2 & " " & Q2,0))




The formula worked as expected, thank you so much for your assistance.
